# Can you set NPP to turn off EOL Conversion

Tags: notepad++

I have data in SQL that I KNOW has Char(10) only for its EOL character.  Thats' fine.  But when troubleshooting things and I copy that value from SSMS and paste into NPP, It changes the CHar(10) to Char(10)+Char(13).   Is there a way to stop it so it will paste whatever you EOL the source system has?

I have poked around online and it doesn't seem like there is, so I thought I'd ask around.

Here is the data I then ran into SSMS with an UPDATE statement with the LF only on it - fine.
[SQL text field with LF as the EOL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twOY8.jpg)

Here it is once I copy/paste that data back into NPP from SSMS with the CR-LF defaulting back in - not desired.
[SQL text field with CR-LF as the EOL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqkKp.jpg)

Is there no way to turn that off so I can have NPP display the correct value from the source system to help in debugging efforts?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) installed. But I have tried under Windows 10 with Notepad++ v 8.5.6 (64bit).

Try the following setting  and customize it for your use case.

First you'd create a small text file **BEFORE** changing the preferences under Windows with the EOL `CRLF` (check and set in the menu ***View > Show Symbol***).

- Now change the preference as shown in the screenshot below.
- Close Notepad++ and restart Notepad++.
- Open your small text file (***File > Open***).
- <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Create a new file (***File > New***)
- <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

I got a `LF` only as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

It is also possible to perform a quick conversion for End of Line (EOL) via the menu. From the main menu try ***Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF)***