# Notepad++ versus Textpad for SQL scripts - Notepad++ sees extra characters

Tags: notepad++, textpad

I used to use Textpad and for some reason I ended up with Notepad++ on my newer computer.
I like Notepad++ now - I use it for writing SQL scripts.
However, when I look at old scripts that I wrote or someone else wrote using Textpad, in Notepad++ I'm seeing extra characters.

Specifically, I'm seeing CR and sometimes CFLF, whereas my new Notepad++ scripts use only CRLF for each line.

I'm trying to show a screenprint here of text that originated from Textpad - but now I want to edit it in Notepad++.

[Screenshot in Notepad++ of Textpad script here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfpzd.png)

This might seem like a minor thing to you all, however when I have a prod support issue and need to start from a prior script...  I'm in a hurry and these extra chars cause extra spaces or line feeds in the script. This causes readability problems - and when I try to remove said extra chars, and then  try to run the script on a Linux server, the script errors.  (Even though when I copy it to SQL developer, the script works just fine! Very Strange!)

I'm looking for a setup or config place to fix these kinds of problems - as opposed to updating all my old scripts.

I really believe I didn't have this issue - and now I suddenly have it.  It's very confusing.

[Screenshot of script Originating from Notepad++ Looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRSGU.png)

Thank you for any help!!! :)

Issue is: When I try to remove said extra chars in Notepad++, and then  try to run the script on a Linux server, the script errors.

UPDATE:
I found that I can convert my text file to UTF-8-BOM under 'Encoding' menu item.  I then tried converting to ANSI - that removed all the extra LF's, So then I used Find-Replace (aka Regex) (Regular Expression) Find \r and Replace with \r\n  and this worked! Then I put it back to UTF-8-BOM.
I also found out that the 2 scripts I recently had trouble with were Very Old.  One even said 'Macintosh' at the bottom.
So therefore, it must be that I'm still ok with Notepad++ and if I get a script from someone else, and the line feeds look off, I'll have to fix it.
There are other Notepad++ stack overflow questions out there having to do with Line feed and newline - that helped. THANKS!! :)

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77840634/1981088

Comment: @help-info.de Thank you!! This link is helpful.